# Mapbox cluster tiles not displaying.

Tags: javascript, geojson, mapbox

I am currently using `Mapbox` in order to complete one of the first examples but something strange is happening. My cluster tiles are not being displayed for some reason. I don't receive any kind of error message and my map is loading perfectly fine. I am currently using data from `usgs.gov` about 4.5 hour earthquake update.

Here is my how I loaded all my `src` and `style` files.

```
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.28.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <script src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet/v0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>
        <script src = "leaflet-providers.js"> </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.28.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
```

I was not using `<script src = "leaflet-providers.js"> </script>` initially but decided to add it to see if it will fix the issue. Well, it didn't.

JS Code as copied from the Tutorial:

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'XXXXXXXX';
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map',
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9',
    center: [-36.77344,  41.138952],
    zoom: 2
});

var nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl();
    map.addControl(nav, 'top-right');

map.on('load', function() {

    // Add a new source from our GeoJSON data and set the
    // 'cluster' option to true.
    map.addSource("earthquakes", {
        type: "geojson",
        // Point to GeoJSON data. This example visualizes all M1.0+ earthquakes
        // from 12/22/15 to 1/21/16 as logged by USGS' Earthquake hazards program.
        data: "https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_hour.geojson",
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
        clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
    });

    // Use the earthquakes source to create five layers:
    // One for unclustered points, three for each cluster category,
    // and one for cluster labels.
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "unclustered-points",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "earthquakes",
        "filter": ["!has", "point_count"],
        "layout": {
            "icon-image": "marker-15"
        }
    });

    // Display the earthquake data in three layers, each filtered to a range of
    // count values. Each range gets a different fill color.
    var layers = [
        [150, '#f28cb1'],
        [20, '#f1f075'],
        [0, '#51bbd6']
    ];

    layers.forEach(function (layer, i) {
        map.addLayer({
            "id": "cluster-" + i,
            "type": "circle",
            "source": "earthquakes",
            "paint": {
                "circle-color": layer[1],
                "circle-radius": 18
            },
            "filter": i === 0 ?
                [">=", "point_count", layer[0]] :
                ["all",
                    [">=", "point_count", layer[0]],
                    ["<", "point_count", layers[i - 1][0]]]
        });
    });

    // Add a layer for the clusters' count labels
    map.addLayer({
        "id": "cluster-count",
        "type": "symbol",
        "source": "earthquakes",
        "layout": {
            "text-field": "{point_count}",
            "text-font": [
                "DIN Offc Pro Medium",
                "Arial Unicode MS Bold"
            ],
            "text-size": 12
        }
    });

});
```

I really don't know why is this happening. Can you please help me figure it out. Should I build a back end in order to constantly refresh the data?

Example I used : [Example from Mapbox website.](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/cluster/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like the data source you use has err or just be empty. here is what I got from querying the datasource https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_hour.geojson:

result:`{"type":"FeatureCollection","metadata":{"generated":1479611702000,"url":"http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_hour.geojson","title":"USGS Magnitude 4.5+ Earthquakes, Past Hour","status":200,"api":"1.5.2","count":0},"features":[]}`

you can try to download data to local and load to map to test the sample code.

Comment: I tried using the default dataset provided in the given example from Mapbox but the result was the same -> missing tiles.

Comment: if you use:data: "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson"

Comment: if you use data: "https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson" directly, you might get CORS err

Comment: So what should I do, should I build a back end for it..or ?

Comment: you can try download that geojson file and put it with your code and then, change the data source to:  data: "./earthquakes.geojson",

Comment: I will do that, even though the whole idea was to fetch live data. I've managed to achieve that using **OpenMaps** and **LeafletJs**. with a `$.getJSON("http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/all_day.geojson", function(data) { 
 addDataToMap(data, map); 
});` but I guess you can't do it with MapBox.

Comment: Not sure how mapbox fetch resource files. But getting resource using javascript would always encounter CORS issue. Besides that, I think what you did should be valid.